# How to insert charactor like "don't" in Sqlite in ios

Tags: ios

I am inserting some keyword like Don't , has'nt in Sqlite which is not inserted.any one have idea about it.

Comment: Use parameterized queries, instead of the injection-prone abomination you're using now that you didn't bother to show us.

Comment: show your insert query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `'` as escape character and insert it like this:

```
dont''t
```

[Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A single quote within the string can be encoded by putting two single quotes in a row - as in Pascal

In case you are using an API to connect with Sqlite, instead of manipulating the original string a better approach would be to use `sqlite3_bind_text()` function to bind a value to a `?` placeholder in the SQL. Thanks to [@Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1271826/) for pointing this out.

Comment: While that's technically correct, probably better than manipulating the original string is to use the `sqlite3_bind_text()` function to bind a value to a `?` placeholder in the SQL.